# How would I create a gui in lua without the use of libraries like that of wxLua?

Tags: user-interface, lua

In my lack of experience I'm not sure if I can ask this in such a way that can be understood.

Basically, I want to make a user interface using raw lua. Is this even possible? If not, how does wxLua create a gui? Does it use another language with a built in GUI library?

I've been trying to figure this out for some time and never find a real answer.

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

Comment: wxLua calls functions from the wxWidgets library which interacts with the window manager to draw windows.  You surely do not want to interact with the window manager directly.  If you really want to do this you can take a look at http://luagl.sourceforge.net/ or https://luapower.com/xlib.  If you want to do it completely without external packages use LuaJIT, load `libGL.so` using FFI and call the C functions directly.  Everything that doesn't involve a higher-level library is of course not platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using the FFI module of [Luajit](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) which can invoke a platform API directly. That is the "raw lua" way to make a user interface.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
int MessageBoxA(void *w, const char *txt, const char *cap, int type);
]]
ffi.C.MessageBoxA(nil, "Hello world!", "Test", 0)
```